# Control docker-compose from Gradle build script

Tags: gradle, docker, docker-compose

For my tests I need to run containers with e.g. some databases. I have set everything using docker-compose, and if containers are up my tests are working. One note: these are not the unit tests, but integration tests, and they are allowed to run longer.

What would be the best way to control docker-compose from Gradle? I need to run the containers (if not up) and fire the tests. This also should work for OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can run `docker-compose up -d` using the [exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) to start the environment.

And you can run `docker-compose stop; docker-compose rm -f` as a cleanup task when the tests are done (if you want to stop everything and remove containers).

Comment: Agree. Just use `exec` task to execute `docker-compose`. You can use `dependsOn` and `finalizedBy` on your `test` task to ensure containers are started and stopped before/after the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Although this questions is already a little old:

I wrote a plugin to do exactly what you want. You can include container definitions in your build script and it will manage container lifecycles directly from Gradle for you:

```
plugins {
  id "com.chrisgahlert.gradle-dcompose-plugin" version "0.8.1"
}

dcompose {
  database {
    image = 'mysql:latest'
    portBindings = ['3306:3306']
  }
}

test {
  dependsOn startDatabaseContainer
  finalizedBy removeDatabaseContainer
}
```

This will start a MySQL database before running `gradle test` and remove it afterwards.

For more details see: https://github.com/chrisgahlert/gradle-dcompose-plugin